# how to clean the contents under C:/Users/tim/appdata?

Tags: windows-7

Under Windows 7, I was wondering  how to clean the contents under C:/Users/tim/appdata? My current one takes up 4 GB. Also, a little explanation about its purpose will be nice!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**AppData** stands for **Application Data**, you most likely don't want to delete anything there...

Mine is also 4 GB, it's completely normal behavior.

Comment: Basically, any time an application needs to store stuff, it goes there rather than in the Program Files directory (for properly designed apps!) This could be anything from personal options setting to your entire email inbox.  Don't touch!

Comment: Over time it will grow. Uninstalled apps don't remove their content.